# search data from XML and writing to anothe xml file with python

Tags: python, xml

I want to know what is the best method to search for data in XML and then once the match is found write all the section to another file, given the following xml:

```
<root>
    <title>
        <control>
            <id>001</id>
            <gas-type>gasoline</gas-type>
            <brand>honda</brand>
        </control>
    </title>
    <title>          
        <control>
            <id>002</id>
            <gas-type>diesel</gas-type>
            <brand>volvo</brand>
        </control>
    </title>
</root>
```

e.g

if the user input is id = '001' then take all the data within the:

```
    <title>
        <control>
            <id>001</id>
            <gas-type>gasoline</gas-type>
            <brand>honda</brand>
        </control>
    </title>
```

and write it in a new file.

so far I found a way to search for the ID:

```
from xml.dom import minidom


mixml="""<root>
    <title>
        <control>
            <id>001</id>
            <gas-type>gasoline</gas-type>
            <brand>honda</brand>
        </control>
    </title>
    <title>          
        <control>
            <id>002</id>
            <gas-type>diesel</gas-type>
            <brand>volvo</brand>
        </control>
    </title>
</root>"""

user = input('id:')

xmldoc = minidom.parseString(mixml)


itemlist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("id")

for i in itemlist:
    if i.firstChild.nodeValue == user:
```

in compares the user input vs the id tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use BeautifulSoup.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(open(your_file,encoding="utf8"), 'html.parser')
contentgroup = soup.find_all('control')
myresult = [item for item in contentgroup if item.id.contents[0]=='001']
```

Result would be:

```
 [<control>
 <id>001</id>
 <gas-type>gasoline</gas-type>
 <brand>honda</brand>
 </control>]
```